# Fx Firm market making

Tags: market-data, fx, market-microstructure, market-making, market-model

I've been doing market making on forex using the last look feature so far. 
Now we are moving to do on firm making, but I'm kind of lost.

To do firm making we need to post resting orders (currenex or integral), how does it work exactly? 
Anyone with experience in this area? Any additional information?

Answer (score 3):

Whereas when you marketmake on a last-look basis:
- You, the marketmaker, are sending indicative prices to the ECN
- The **ECN**  sends orders to you and is at risk (since you have the option to reject, hopefully rarely)

When you marketmake on a no-last-look (NLL) basis:
- the ECN is sending indicative prices 
- You, the **marketmaker**, send orders to the ECN and you are at risk unless you cancel such orders (and your ability to do so depends on the reaction time of your model, latency between you and the ECN and the ECN reaction time).

Some ECNs provide only one API both for taking and NLL marketmaking. On those you are using their standard API that allows aggressive orders (IOCs) and passive, resting orders (e.g. GTCs). You, as an NLL marketmaker are just using the GTC order types and sending cancels every time you wish to change or cancel your price.

Other ECNs do provide a separate API for NLL marketmaking, a significant feature being that you will not match with other marketmakers.  If you contact me directly (my contacts should be visible in my profile) I can explain which are which.

Comment: Now, my confusion is with those who use same API to make and aggress. The only difference between making and taking would be time in force on your order? (GTC or IOC)?... So  let say that as a maker I want to buy, then I should post my GTC orders at market bid?